# Accordion body dynamic content not working properly - Angular + ngbAccordion

Tags: angular, accordion, ng-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I have an accordion that loops through a array and based on a condition the content inside the accordion body should load dynamically.

```
items = [
{
data: 'test1',
item: []
},{
data: 'test2',
item: []
},{
data: 'test3',
item: []
},
]
```

```
<div ngbAccordion *ngFor="let i of items">
  <div
    ngbAccordionItem
    #item="ngbAccordionItem"
    [collapsed]="false"
    class="item"
  >
    <div ngbAccordionHeader ngbAccordionToggle>{{ i.data }}</div>
    <div ngbAccordionCollapse>
      <div ngbAccordionBody>
        <div *ngIf="i.data === 'test1'">1</div>
        <div *ngIf="i.data === 'test2'">2</div>
        <div *ngIf="i.data === 'test3'">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when the accordion body loads it always loads the first element after matching the correct condition.

This is how my result looks like:

[image: result]

Current Result:

```
________
|test2 |
________
| 2    |
| 1    |
--------
```

Expected Result:

```
________
|test2 |
________
| 2    |
--------
```

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong here.
I tried with `ngSwitch` and had the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the NgbAccordionBody directive [API documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/api#NgbAccordionBody) and the [usage](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/overview#basic-usage), you should provide the content in the `<ng-template>` element.

> The actual content is provided in a child ng-template element. Depending on the state of the accordion, the template will be either inserted or removed from the DOM.

```
<div ngbAccordionBody>
  <ng-template>
    <div *ngIf="i.data === 'test1'">1</div>
    <div *ngIf="i.data === 'test2'">2</div>
    <div *ngIf="i.data === 'test3'">3</div>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cdpeds?file=src%2Fmain.ts)